# How do I stop a Python program from closing when I run it from its saved location Python version 3.6.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a very simple Python program that just has a few print statements in it. When I run it from the IDE it runs fine. However, when I try to open up the program from my desktop (where I saved it) it opens runs and immediately closes.

How can I keep it open? Is there a statement or some function I need to add at the end or beginning?

Comment: how are you opening it from your desktop? using command prompt?

Comment: No I saved it to my desktop and just clicked on the icon it created but @Hasan Alper Ocalan solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below line end of your code. It will wait until you press enter.

```
input("Press enter")
```

You can delete the text like below :

```
input("")
```

Comment: That worked thank you very much!!!! I just needed it to leave the message up!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using some kind of Windows OS, you can try to open command line window by hitting Ctrl+R and typing

```
cmd
```

after that you should be able to run your python script by typing

```
python c:/path/to/the/script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in a command shell instead of just double-clicking on the python file, the command shell will stay open, allowing you to see the output.